# multiple chartjs charts with the same configuration but different data

Tags: javascript, html, function, chart.js

In my script i am using a function to create the configuration for my chart.
When I use the function to create my  first chart everything works fine. But when i use it the secound time with different data, the chart didnt appear. Can anyone explain why it doesnt work and maybe update my code that it work? Hope you understand my problem

Coding below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-row; height: 300px;">
            <div style="width:25%; display: table-cell;">
                <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div style="width:25%; display: table-cell;">
                <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div style="width:25%; display: table-cell;">
                <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div style="width:25%; display: table-cell;">
                <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script>

    function chartconfig(data, label, labels) {
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;
        config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    data,
                    backgroundColor: ['rgb(0, 140, 75)', 'rgb(94, 140, 0)'],
                    label,
                    labels,
                    hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                    fill: false,
                },],
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        color: '#000',
                        align: 'start',
                        anchor: 'end',
                        display: 'auto',
                        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                            let sum = ctx.dataset._meta[0].total;
                            let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
                            let text = value + '\n' + percentage;
                            return text;
                        },
                    }
                },
                rotation: -0.8 * Math.PI,
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: '#000',
                        generateLabels: () => {
                            let labels = [];
                            config.data.datasets.forEach((ds, iDs) => labels = labels.concat(ds.labels.map((l, iLabel) => ({
                                datasetIndex: iDs,
                                labelIndex: iLabel,
                                text: l,
                                fillStyle: ds.backgroundColor[iLabel],
                                hidden: chart ? chart.getDatasetMeta(iDs).data[iLabel].hidden : false,
                                strokeStyle: '#fff'
                            }))));
                            return labels;
                        }
                    },
                    onClick: (event, legendItem) => {
                        let metaData = chart.getDatasetMeta(legendItem.datasetIndex).data;
                        metaData[legendItem.labelIndex].hidden = !metaData[legendItem.labelIndex].hidden;
                        chart.update();
                    }
                },
                tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
                            let dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                            let index = tooltipItem.index;
                            return dataset.labels[index] + ": " + dataset.data[index];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return config;
    }

    function addData(data, backgroundColor, labels) {
        chart.data.datasets.push({
            data,
            backgroundColor,
            labels,
            fill: false,
        });
        chart.update();
    }

    var data = [160, 150,];
    var label = ['Februar'];
    var labels = ['21.02.2020', '22.02.2020'];
    
    var config = chartconfig(data, label, labels);
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx1, config); // worked fine and appears

    var data = [120, 230,];
    var label = ['März'];
    var labels = ['21.03.2020', '22.03.2020'];

    var config = chartconfig(data, label, labels);
    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx2, config); //didnt appear

</script>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the datalabels formatter where the _meta index is not always 0. If you use multiple charts second chart index is 1 and third chart index is 2 etc.
I added this line of code to get current metaIndex using Object.keys()

```
let metaIndex = Object.keys(ctx.dataset._meta)[0]
let sum = ctx.dataset._meta[metaIndex].total;
```

Here is the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-row; height: 300px;">
            <div style="width:25%; display: table-cell;">
                <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div style="width:25%; display: table-cell;">
                <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div style="width:25%; display: table-cell;">
                <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div style="width:25%; display: table-cell;">
                <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>

      function chartconfig(data, label, labels) {
          Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
          Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;
          config = {
              type: 'doughnut',
              data: {
                  datasets: [{
                      data,
                      backgroundColor: ['rgb(0, 140, 75)', 'rgb(94, 140, 0)'],
                      label,
                      labels,
                      hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                      fill: false,
                  },],
              },
              options: {
                  plugins: {
                      datalabels: {
                          color: '#000',
                          align: 'start',
                          anchor: 'end',
                          display: 'auto',
                          formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                              let chartIndex = Object.keys(ctx.dataset._meta)[0]
                              let sum = ctx.dataset._meta[chartIndex].total;
                              let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
                              let text = value + '\n' + percentage;
                              return text;
                          },
                      }
                  },
                  rotation: -0.8 * Math.PI,
                  legend: {
                      position: 'bottom',
                      labels: {
                          fontColor: '#000',
                          generateLabels: () => {
                              let labels = [];
                              config.data.datasets.forEach((ds, iDs) => labels = labels.concat(ds.labels.map((l, iLabel) => ({
                                  datasetIndex: iDs,
                                  labelIndex: iLabel,
                                  text: l,
                                  fillStyle: ds.backgroundColor[iLabel],
                                  hidden: chart ? chart.getDatasetMeta(iDs).data[iLabel].hidden : false,
                                  strokeStyle: '#fff'
                              }))));
                              return labels;
                          }
                      },
                      onClick: (event, legendItem) => {
                          let metaData = chart.getDatasetMeta(legendItem.datasetIndex).data;
                          metaData[legendItem.labelIndex].hidden = !metaData[legendItem.labelIndex].hidden;
                          chart.update();
                      }
                  },
                  tooltips: {
                      callbacks: {
                          label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
                              let dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                              let index = tooltipItem.index;
                              return dataset.labels[index] + ": " + dataset.data[index];
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          };
          return config;
      }
  
      function addData(data, backgroundColor, labels) {
          chart.data.datasets.push({
              data,
              backgroundColor,
              labels,
              fill: false,
          });
          chart.update();
      }
  
      var data = [160, 150,];
      var label = ['Februar'];
      var labels = ['21.02.2020', '22.02.2020'];
      
      var config = chartconfig(data, label, labels);
      var ctx1 = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
      var chart = new Chart(ctx1, config); // worked fine and appears
  
      var data = [120, 230,];
      var label = ['März'];
      var labels = ['21.03.2020', '22.03.2020'];
  
      var config = chartconfig(data, label, labels);
      var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
      var chart = new Chart(ctx2, config); //didnt appear
  
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```